# Select node by InnerText wont work if the InnerText contains whitespaces

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to get a specific node's element name.
To do that i loop through all the document's descendants and find the one that matches a specific innerText but it doesnt work when the node that its in contains
whitespaces.

My code

```
var targetElementNodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => d.InnerText.Contains(target_title)).ToList();
```

I tried using the `Trim()` method but nothing changed

```
var targetElementNodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => d.InnerText.Trim().Contains(target_title.Trim())).ToList();
```

I copy the `target_title` directly from the website

Example of a node with spaces:

```
<a itemprop="url" href="somthing/" rel="bookmark">
                                                ASUS HYPER M.2 X16 CARD
                                            </a>
```

Comment: Trim won't remove the new line characters...or the spaces after the first new line or spaces before last new line.

Comment: Damn, i didnt realize its actualy a new line not just whitespaces, thanks for the observation